# How Can I Set The Range Of the X and Y Axis For A Heatmap?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, axis

I am trying to set the axes for both x and y but every time I try it, the heatmap shrinks to a corner of the plot. I try

```
plt.xlim(0, 60)
plt.ylim(0, 30)
```

I've also tried:

```
ax.set_ylim(0, 30)
ax.set_xlim(0, 60)
```

But this does the same thing.

Here's what I have so far to call the heatmap:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index = 'Test X', columns = 'Test Y', values = 'Data')
ax = sns.heatmap(pivot, annot = True, fmt = .2g, cmap = 'Blues_r')
```

I want the X-axis to go from 0 - 60 and for it to show the range regardless of the data going to 60 or not and the same with y to 30.
But this does not work.

Comment: Setting the limits is useless, because the data itself is just between 0 and N, with N being the number of rows/columns of the array. You can decide if you want to change the ticklabels, or if you want to use some matplotlib function like `imshow` or `pcolormesh` that would obey to some actual data coordinates.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am using seaborn so I'm not sure how to incorporate that in there using a different call. I did another edit and added some more code to help.

Comment: If you want to use seaborn, you can customize the tick positions and ticklabels of the axes. But you don't have to use seaborn, right? So you could use pcolormesh, where instead of `sns.heatmap(z, ...)` you use `plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z)` with x and y being the vectors of coordinates you want your pixels to be positionned at.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest If I do use seaborn, would changing the labels suffice? Or will it just change the name of the tick. I thought it wouldn't actually make a difference on the axis.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change the axis; that's the point. If you want to use seaborn, you cannot change the axis because the Nth pixel just has the coordinate N-1. So what remains is to keep the axis as it is, but fake the labels to read what you want them to read.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So if I use pcolormesh, would my initial calls to limit the range work?

Comment: I have no idea, because I don't know the data (see [mcve]).

Answer (score -4):

By using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((15,15)))
sns.heatmap(df)
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim(0, 60)
```

I was able to get the figure with the required limits

[image]

Also, `ax=sns.heatmap(df); ax.set_xlim(0, 60)` behave in the same way. Perhaps is the way you're calling `ax.set_xlim`. Hope it helps